# Why Tomcat is using different threads when request url is same and handled with CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, spring-boot, completable-future

I have used [this sample](https://github.com/nickebbitt/rest-async-completable-future) in github using CompletableFuture.

I tried running /asyncCompletable endpoint from several tabs in browser(chrome) simultaneously.
The point is as Tomcat is Servlet Container and it has it's own Servlet Thread Pool, thus hitting same endpoint url from different tabs in browser wouldn't necessarily use same main-thread. see my console log below:

```
8:07:07.334 [http-nio-9191-exec-8] Request received
18:07:07.335 [http-nio-9191-exec-8] Servlet thread released
18:07:07.335 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] Start processing request
18:07:08.262 [http-nio-9191-exec-7] Request received
18:07:08.262 [http-nio-9191-exec-7] Servlet thread released
18:07:08.262 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4] Start processing request
18:07:08.860 [http-nio-9191-exec-9] Request received
18:07:08.861 [http-nio-9191-exec-9] Servlet thread released
18:07:08.861 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5] Start processing request
18:07:09.376 [http-nio-9191-exec-10] Request received
18:07:09.377 [http-nio-9191-exec-10] Servlet thread released
```

As you see it is using different threads for each browser tab for the same URL and not reusing the released thread for further calls.
What I mean is that it is not reusing the released thread (for example http-nio-9191-exec-7) for next incoming request.
Why is that?

Comment: Why _should_ it?

Comment: Since CompletableFuture guarantees that current thread(main thread) will not blocked and for any async call a new thread will be assigned. but as you can see from my log, the main thread (which has http-nio-9191-exec- prefix) is not same despite being released immediately when called by client.

Comment: So? You haven't explained why the thread _ought_ to be immediately reused instead of (as is apparently the case) placed into a queue for reuse.

Comment: So you mean, it is placed in thread-pool again and is available for other incoming request?

Comment: That would be my guess. You haven't explained why you expect the specific behavior you expect.

Comment: I did expect because I wasn't sure whether this is the default behavior of Tomcat or not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thread pool is what it states - a pool. So there's no guarantees in a pool to re-address the same thread to a task nor would it be any helpful. The pool just return the next available thread in the pool. But what does "next" mean? This is depending on the pool implementation - and this should be abstracted from the user. Just because it's not directly reassigned the next request doesn't mean it will never be reused. The pool decides how to do this. This depends in the pool's strategy. So there might be some margin or threshold in time or some queue in the Servlet pool.

You could try if behaviour changes when you reconfigure Tomcat for evaluation purpose:

```
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="0"/>
```

But this will not be helpful performance wise and is not suggested. I wouldn't mess with the Servlet Thread Pool mechanics unless there's good reasons to do so. A pool is for handing over that control for good reasons.

Comment: Thanks , I actually configured "server.tomcat.max-threads=1" in application.properties and test it. Since Now Tomcat is having 1 thread in its thread pool several call to the endpoint (that is "/asyncCompletable") will use only 1 thread and my log is showing one main thread per each call which makes use of new Thread in commonPool of CompletableFuture for running Async task.

Comment: But another question arise now and that is since I have configured Tomcat to have only one thread when calling /asyncCompltable endpoint which is using CompletableFuture.supplyAsync method, it is still using different thread than main thread? How is that?

Comment: Cite: "The problem is, supplyAsync() by default uses ForkJoinPool.commonPool(), thread pool shared between all CompletableFutures, all parallel streams and all applications deployed on the same JVM (if you are unfortunate to still use application server with many deployed artifacts). This hard-coded, unconfigurable thread pool is completely outside of our control, hard to monitor and scale. Therefore you should always specify your own Executor..."

https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2015/11/which-thread-executes.html